# SharePoint Online - Custom List - Permission on Based on Department Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, custom-list, filter

I have a custom list with 200 records/items and there is a column (lookup) with department names (about 20 department).  I want to give access to number of items based on the department.  A similar example would be a Contact List with multiple department so Marketing Dept should see only staff details for their dept.

I was thinking of using filters but I think users will be able to access the full list through URL which is not ideal. I could also break the inheritance and assign permission to individual items but that would be very hard to manage when number of items increase.

Are there any other ways to achieve this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Filters aren't true security as you note. You could add folders to the list and secure the folders, then only the users who have access to the folders would see the information below. Item level permission performance scales horribly and is a pain to maintain.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Performance was one of the reasons, I wanted to avoid item level permissions.  Folder level permission is not ideal solution but I will give it a try.